# I am trying to write shell script to copy bamboo builds to spaces with build number

Tags: shell, digital-ocean, bamboo

I have created `SSH` task in bamboo whereas whenever the plan is run it has to copy that build ex, .jar or .war files to `DigitalOcean` Spaces.I have written below script and its working fine

```
#!/bin/bash 
DATETIME=`date +%y%m%d-%H_%M_%S`

SRC=dist

DST=s3://bucket_name

NAME=Certified_artifact

tar -czvf $NAME-$DATETIME.tar.gz dist;

~/s3cmd-2.0.1/s3cmd put $NAME-$DATETIME.tar.gz s3://bucket_name;

rm $NAME-$DATETIME.tar.gz
```

But I need to copy with build numbers version it creates rather datetime. Could someone please help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this script is in Bamboo you can use the built in variable ${bamboo.buildNumber}.  Otherwise, you can use the argument field in Bamboo to pass this number into your script.

So your script would change to:

```
#!/bin/bash 
SRC=dist

DST=s3://bucket_name

NAME=Certified_artifact

tar -czvf $NAME-${Bamboo.buildNumber}.tar.gz dist;

~/s3cmd-2.0.1/s3cmd put $NAME-${Bamboo.buildNumber}.tar.gz s3://bucket_name;

rm $NAME-${Bamboo.buildNumber}.tar.gz
```

Alternatively you could set the build number at the start of the script the way you oringally were with the Datetime

Comment: Hi, I am New to Bamboo could you please help me elaborating the solution. how to achieve it. The above script i am using as part of bamboo SSH task.

Comment: @NaveenNK answer updated with what the script should look like.